# Why is UIButton highlight area so small?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a UIButton pretty big in area but when tappedm the highlighted area is very small, why so? I've spent the past coulpe of hours looking for an answer and have had no luck. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Area in storyboard]

[image: highlighted area]

Comment: That doesn't look like a standard UIButton.. Are you using an image in the button, or are you using a subclass of UIButton..

Comment: @Ron I think it is standard. I dragged it into my storyboard and added outlets and ibactions, nothing else.

Comment: thats's definitely not a standard `UIButton`. Standard `UIButtons` change font color (by default).

Answer (score 0):

I think, highlighted area is according to the size of the characters.
If you want to spread the highlighted area, increase the text size or use an image file of the character in the large size background.

Comment: I see where you're going there but still no fix, it just makes the highlight proportional to a bigger font size. I'm trying to find how to increase the highlight, seeing as the frame is so much bigger, seems logical that there should be a way.